# Firebase Moving one item to another node

Tags: android, json, data-structures, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What If I want to move one item from the "Private" node, like this one: `"2016-06-01 23:40:08"`  to the location of the "Work" node with the correct year and month node. Do I use the onChildMoved() to move it and how do I really get it into the right nodes

**JSON**

```
  {
  "users" : {
    "S1PtLPZ1mISXsbwpbz1NoLclpAV2" : {
      "email" : "kalle@hotmail.se"
    },
    "aBZtC3VjpPc8o40AjA9sGZg0TC23" : {
      "email" : "skola@hotmail.com",
      "waypoints" : {
        "Private" : {
          "2016" : {
            "06" : {
              "2016-06-01 23:40:08" : {
                "destination" : "Västerlånggatan 10, 451 31 Uddevalla, Sweden",
                "distance" : "8.9 m",
                "duration" : "1 min",
                "encodedLatLngs" : "{sccJaoygA?]",
                "origin" : "Västerlånggatan 10, 451 31 Uddevalla, Sweden",
                "timeStamp" : "2016-06-01 23:40:08",
              },
              "2016-06-01 23:40:51" : {
                "destination" : "Västerlånggatan 8, 451 31 Uddevalla, Sweden",
                "distance" : "34.7 m",
                "duration" : "1 min",
                "encodedLatLngs" : "yoccJsoygA}@B",
                "origin" : "Västerlånggatan 4, 451 50 Uddevalla, Sweden",
                "timeStamp" : "2016-06-01 23:40:51",
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Work" : {
            "2016" : {
            "06" : {
              "2016-03-01 21:40:08" : {
```

**Demo**

```
         FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    String mUserId = user.getUid();

                    final String mTravelType = "Private";
                    final String year = "2016";
                    final String month = "06";
                    final String key = "2016-06-01 23:40:08";


                    String waypointsUrl = Constants.FIREBASE_URL_MAIN_REF + "/users/" + mUserId + "/waypoints";
                    mWaypointRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(waypointsUrl);



                    // NEW VALUES
                    mDateRef = mWaypointRef.child("Work").child(year).child(month).child(key);
                    final String newValues = mDateRef.toString();
                    Log.i("path to new values", newValues);
                    // https://rjcar3.firebaseio.com/users/waypoints/Work/2016/06


                    // OLD VALUES
                    mDateRef = mWaypointRef.child(mTravelType).child(year).child(month).child(key);
                    final String oldValues = mDateRef.toString();
                    Log.i("path to old values", oldValues);
                    //https://rjcar3.firebaseio.com/users/waypoints/Private/2016/06/



                    mDateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            // MyClass is your POJO Class (class representing the node with it's children)
                            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#update_specific_fields
                            MyWaypoint node = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyWaypoint.class);
                            Log.i("Node", node.toString());


                            //Because the key is not a child you need to set it manually
                            node.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());


                            //You need to create a toMap() method for your class in order to save the values to the new location
                            Map<String, Object> nodeValues = node.toMap();

                            Log.i("nodeValues", nodeValues.values() + "");
                            Log.i("nodesSize", nodeValues.size() + "");

                            //Here you create the updates you want to execute
                            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                            //Save in the new location
                            //The path should be from waypoints to the key  ex: "Work/2016/06/2016-06-1 23:40:08"
                            childUpdates.put(newValues + node.getKey(), nodeValues);


                            for (Object item : childUpdates.values()){
                               Log.i("loop",item.toString());
                            }

                            for (Object item : nodeValues.values()){
                                Log.i("looop",item.toString());

                            }

                            //Erase the old location
                            //The path should be from waypoints to the key  ex: "Private/2016/06/2016-06-1 23:40:08"
                            childUpdates.put(oldValues + node.getKey(), null);

                            mWaypointRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
```

**CatLog**

```
06-02 19:51:47.555 6872-6872/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar I/path to old values: https://rjcar3.firebaseio.com/users/aBZtC3VjpPc8o40AjA9sGZg0TC23/waypoints/Private/2016/06
06-02 19:51:47.555 6872-6872/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar I/path to new values: https://rjcar3.firebaseio.com/users/aBZtC3VjpPc8o40AjA9sGZg0TC23/waypoints/Work/2016/06
06-02 19:51:47.577 6872-6872/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar I/Node: com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar.POJO_Firebase.MyWaypoint@286ef13
06-02 19:51:47.578 6872-6872/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar I/nodeValues: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
06-02 19:51:47.578 6872-6872/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar I/mWaypointRef: https://rjcar3.firebaseio.com/users/aBZtC3VjpPc8o40AjA9sGZg0TC23/waypoints
06-02 19:51:47.761 6872-7027/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /users/aBZtC3VjpPc8o40AjA9sGZg0TC23/waypoints failed: DatabaseError: Invalid token in path
```

**POJO Class**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class MyWaypoint {

    private String encodedLatLngs;
    private String duration;
    private String destination;
    private String distance;
    private String origin;
    private String timeStamp;
    private String key;

    public MyWaypoint() {
    }


    public MyWaypoint(String timeStamp, String origin, String destination, String duration, String distance, String encodedLatLngs, String key) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.encodedLatLngs = encodedLatLngs;
        this.key = key;
    }


    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("key", key);
        result.put("destination", destination);
        result.put("distance", distance);
        result.put("duration", duration);
        result.put("origin", origin);
        result.put("timeStamp", timeStamp);
        result.put("encodedLatLngs", encodedLatLngs);
        return result;
    }


    public void setKey(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }


    public String getEncodedLatLngs() {
        return encodedLatLngs;
    }

    public void setEncodedLatLngs(String encodedLatLngs) {
        this.encodedLatLngs = encodedLatLngs;
    }


    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }


    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }


    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: An off-topic question, I'm new to Firebase: I still don't understand why we need toMap() function, isn't it possible to directly use the node java object like it can be done using setValue(node)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've checked your code and changed it, just edit my default strings and it should work Hope it helps...

The errors were:
1) The path was adding an extra key date
2) In the toMap() we were adding an extra key

ok Here is the main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference waypointRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String mTravelType = "Private";
        final String year = "2016";
        final String month = "06";
        final String dateKey = "2016-06-01 23:40:08";
        String mUserId = user.getUid();

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");

        waypointRef = myRef.child(mUserId).child("waypoints");
        Log.e("ref",waypointRef.toString());

        waypointRef.child(mTravelType).child(year).child(month).child(dateKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e("data",dataSnapshot.toString());

                MyClass node = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
                node.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                Map<String, Object> nodeValues = node.toMap();

                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                String work_path = "/Work/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + "/" + dateKey + "/";
                String private_path = "/Private/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + dateKey + "/";

                childUpdates.put(work_path, nodeValues);
                childUpdates.put(private_path, null);

                waypointRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And here is the Class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class MyClass {
    private String key;
    private String destination, distance;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("destination", destination);
        result.put("distance", distance);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: How you mean single observer of type value? `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` ? updated my code some

Comment: Yes exactly, i updated the answer to clarify with your updated code, so you can check it out

Comment: Thanks really close now, but getting this, se update - No setter/field for 2016-06-01 23:41:57

Comment: i've updated the answer, this happens because the key is not a child is not automatically saved in your class so you have to do it manually

Comment: Still nothing happens, Getting null on all my node values. I/nodeValues: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: And if i put breakpoint at this Log.I()  I can see the values of the DataSnapshot of my database

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#update_specific_fields check the example of the Post class

Comment: posted the pojo, it should be okey what I can see

Comment: The fields is all empty for all the 7 fields from the pojo

Comment: Think I nearly got to work now, I get the values, now I just need to make the update happen, updated my code

Comment: i updated the answer with the correct code (using your code as base)

Comment: 06-02 21:14:59.030 12848-12848/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar E/ref: https://rjcar3.firebaseio.com/users/aBZtC3VjpPc8o40AjA9sGZg0TC23/waypoints
06-02 21:14:59.047 12848-12848/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar E/data: DataSnapshot { key = 2016-06-01 23:40:08, value = {origin=Västerlånggatan 10, 451 31 Uddevalla, Sweden, destination=Västerlånggatan 10, 451 31 Uddevalla, Sweden, distance=8.9 m, duration=1 min, timeStamp=2016-06-01 23:40:08, encodedLatLngs={sccJaoygA?]} }

Comment: The Work node got deleted and all items where added to the Private, so something is still wrong.

Comment: Thats because you cannot just copy the code, you have to adjust the references to your project....the functionality of moving from one node to another though is working

Comment: You did those wrong just, update it so can we close this thread :)      String private_path = "/Private/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + dateKey + "/";
                                String work_path = "/Work/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + "/" + dateKey + "/";